# How to get JSON data from multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, getjson

I need to get data from two URLs and fetch them to a single table. How can I do that? Can anybody help me how to do that? Thanks in advance.

What I tried is here. But it shows nothing.

```
var url1 = 'http://localhost:8080/WebService/rest/payment/get/payment';
var url2 = 'http://localhost:8080/WebService/rest/orderdetails/get/all';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.when(
    $.getJSON(url1),
    $.getJSON(url2)).done(function(result1, result2) {
    var table = $("#oTable");
    $.each(result1, result2, function(i, value) {
      table.append('<tr><td>1</td><td class="txt-oflo">' + value.payment + '</td><td>' + value.username + '</td><td class="txt-oflo">' + value.date + '</td><td><span class="text-success">' + value.price + '</span></td><td><a href=""><button class="btn btn-success">Place</button></a>  <a href=""><button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button></a></td></tr>');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the more modern version of requests with `fetch` and use `Promise.all` and `await`, supported natively:

```
const url1 = 'http://localhost:8080/WebService/rest/payment/get/payment';
const url2 = 'http://localhost:8080/WebService/rest/orderdetails/get/all';
const fetchJSON = url => fetch(url).then(response => response.json())

$(document).ready(async () => {
  const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all(fetchJSON(url1), fetchJSON(url2));
  const results = [...result1, ...result2];
  const table = $("#oTable");
  results.forEach((value) => (
      table.append('<tr><td>1</td><td class="txt-oflo">' + value.payment + '</td><td>' + value.username + '</td><td class="txt-oflo">' + value.date + '</td><td><span class="text-success">' + value.price + '</span></td><td><a href=""><button class="btn btn-success">Place</button></a>  <a href=""><button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button></a></td></tr>')
  ));
});
```

Comment: When something doesn't work, please explain *what about it* isn't working, otherwise it's pretty impossible to debug.

Answer (score 1):

deferred.done() -  Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved.

You don't see the response may be because one of the promises is rejected. Try using deferred.then()

Or loop result1 and result2 separately

```
$.each(result1, function(i, value) {
  table.append('<tr><td>1</td><td class="txt-oflo">' + value.payment + '</td><td>' + value.username + '</td><td class="txt-oflo">' + value.date + '</td><td><span class="text-success">' + value.price + '</span></td><td><a href=""><button class="btn btn-success">Place</button></a>  <a href=""><button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button></a></td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: Looping result1 and result2 separately didn't work. It gives values seperately.

Comment: Concat the result1 and result2 then loop it.

Comment: How to concat ?

Comment: Something like 

var result1 = [{name: "Person1"}, {name: "Person2"}, {name: "Person3"}];
var result2 = [{name: "Person4"}, {name: "Person5"}, {name: "Person6"}];
var result3 = result1.concat(result2);